# React JS : Rendering parent componet from child

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components in react js :-

SearchPage

TableView

From searchPage I render TableView. TableView is the child component of SearchPage.

In TableView I have a list of div elements. When I click on any element it should render SearchPage again.

Is there any possible ways to render a parent from the child component with a parameter value?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "When I click on any element it should render SearchPage again." do you want to rerender the whole page?

Comment: yes I want to render the whole page. Actually I want to update parent state based on an action in child component.

Comment: so you'd better rename the title accordingly, as this is the question you're really interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a callback to the child as a prop, in the callback you setState. The child calls the callback like `this.props.something()`.

An alternative is a flux store, which is explained in the other answered.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possible ways to render a parent from the child component
>   with a parameter value?

Yes. What you're looking for is updating the state of your Parent component based on an action in a child component.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I want to update parent state based on an action in child component

Using ReactJS, you want to have a [**unidirectional dataflow**](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). Thus, what you need is a store, where components can

1. write to
2. listen to (or register).

Every component that registers for that store should be informed, when the store has been updated, so that this component can update itself.

I therefore suggest to use a so called [Flux store](http://facebook.github.io/flux/).

Alternatively have a look at [Immstruct](https://github.com/omniscientjs/immstruct) in combination with [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)